# printf not working on C32 compiler

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, mplab

Why isn't the printf working on PIC32 like with PIC18?

For example this code works fine on PIC18, but not on PIC32,

```
printf("%lu",value);
```

With C32 compiler there is not output message, what did I miss?

Comment: Did you try flushing the stream?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I am using MPLAB C32 compiler by the way.

Comment: `printf` uses a buffer, so have you tried using `fflush(stdout)` to see what you wanted to print was just still in the buffer?

Comment: I used `fflush(stdout)` after the printf, I didn't see anything.

Comment: What are the 6 sizes: sizeof(unsigned), sizeof(value), sizeof(unsigned long) on the PIC18, PIC32?  I suspect the answer will unfold.

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof(unsigned) on a PIC18 is 2
The sizeof(unsigned) on a PIC32 is 4
I suspect `value` is not `long unsigned` and so you have UB in

```
printf("%lu",value);
```

If so, insure the format specifier matches the variable type.

Comment: my variable is defined as unsigned long